# CSS: What is causing these small horizontal spaces between my divs?

Tags: css, html, spacing

I have six divs ('group') all contained within a parent div ('groupwhite'), and everything is behaving normally with one exception: there is a small horizontal space between each of my group divs. I can't figure out what is causing it. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="groups">
    <div class="groupwhite">
            <div class="group">
                <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
                <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
                <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
                <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
                <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
                <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
                <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.groupwhite {


font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 110%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 88%;
  margin: 65px auto 65px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 26px 26px 24px 26px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  behavior: url(lib/PIE.htc); }
  @media (max-width: 490px) {
    .groupwhite {
      padding: 26px 18px 24px 18px; } }

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px; }

a {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word; }

div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; }

.group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: cyan;
  vertical-align: top; }

.grouptitle {
  font-size: 135%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px; }

.grouptext {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word; }
```

And here's a picture of my quandary:[image: What is causing these gaps?]

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: Hey thanks for the responses everybody. It is indeed a result of HTML interpreting the whitespace between my 'group' div elements. I fixed it like this:

```
        <div class="group">
            <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here<a></p>
            <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div><div class="group">
            <p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here<a></p>
            <p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
```

Sorry for posting a question so similar to one previously answered!

Comment: Your question is the same as one posted earlier today. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315826/basic-css-positioning-fitting-children-in-container/21315855#21315855

Comment: Technically this question is not related to CSS, but I understand that you might not know that (because you're asking this question). Mind removing the css tag?

Comment: I could if you like, but might it help future searches for a similar problem if I left it in?

Comment: @Ber this is not a solution for ur question, remove the html warnings by adding close tags for `a` element(`</a>`) is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks Dave, bios and rvighne for pointing that out! (I had missed the closing tag on my links)

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept the answer that worked for you. It's considered bad to edit your *question* saying that an *answer* worked.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry! Not enough time had passed when I first tried and I forgot to go back and check an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line breaks between the divs are causing the spacing. HTML interprets all whitespace (newlines, tabs, real spaces) and runs of whitespace as if it were a single normal space.

To fix, just make sure that the div's end tag is flush with the next div's open tag. Like so:

```
</div><div class="group"> <!-- no line break, no whitespace, nothing at all -->
```

Answer (score 2):

it's a natural space added by `display: inline-block` you can either use `float` or you can use a bit of a hack by adding `font-size: 0` to `.groupwhite` and then overriding the text size inside that container

Here is a link about fixes:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Nope, inline-block doesn't change anything except the fact that it's in the same line as surrounding text. Float won't fix it.

Comment: you're wrong. That's exactly what it is. Check out this fiddle, I changed `inline-block` to `float:left` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQBLk/) Change it back to inline block and you'll see the space. Then try that hack and you'll see it works

Comment: @jmore009 JSFiddle doesnt display the "lines" with the code the OP provided, the only thing your edit did (at least for me) was float the entire group to the left

Comment: this is a well documented issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin

Comment: @jmore009 I see, but now you have another problem. The float changes the appearance of the document, definitely undesirable.

Comment: @CumminUp07 take out `float: left` on `.group` and add `display: inline:block` and that was the OP's code

Comment: I understand, that's why I said to use the font-size hack, those are the two ways to handle this issue