# jQuery: Having trouble with not and multiple selectors for CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, conditional-statements

I've got a number of divs (CSS class 'group'), and when one is clicked in, the others are hidden and the clicked on one is expanded (gaining the 'detailed' CSS class). Then, when the expanded div ('.group .detailed) is clicked on, it should resize and lose the 'detailed' class. My problem is, I can't get click events on 'group' divs that also contain 'detailed' to be ignored by my first jquery function and activate my second jquery function. Here's my code:

```
$('.group:not(.detailed)').mousedown(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var speed = 3250;
    var offset = {x : $self.offset().left, y : $self.offset().top};

    readyAnimation();

    $('.group').not($self).addClass('hide');
    $self.animate({'width' : '100%', 'height' : '+=' + '300px'}, {left: 'offset.x' + 'px', top: 'offset.y' + 'px'}, speed);

    function readyAnimation () {
        $self.css({display : 'block'});
        $self.css({'-webkit-box-sizing' : 'border-box', '-moz-box-sizing' : 'border-box', 'box-sizing' : 'border-box'});
        $self.css({margin : '0px'});
    };

    $self.addClass('detailed');
});


$('.group.detailed').mousedown(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var size = '300px';
    var speed = 3250;

    console.log("it worked");

    resetAnimation();

    $self.animate({'width' : size, 'height' : size}, speed)
    $('.group').removeClass('hide');

    function resetAnimation () {
        $self.css({display : ''}); //Empty quotes resets the CSS value to what it was originally (in the CSS file)
        $self.css({'-webkit-box-sizing' : '', '-moz-box-sizing' : '', 'box-sizing' : ''});
        $self.css({margin : ''});
    };

    $self.removeClass('detailed');
});
```

I don't think I need to post my HTML and CSS for this, but they can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324061/css-what-is-causing-these-small-horizontal-spaces-between-my-divs) in a previous question I asked. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: [Here's a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V93dq/)

EDIT 2: See vahapwns, Jonathan and giordanolima's answers for working demonstrations of the code. By combining the two functions togother and using an if statement checking for 'detailed', problems arising from the first function overriding the second are solved. Thanks everybody for your input.

Comment: Create a finddle plese - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here's the fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/V93dq/

Comment: The problem is not the first function overriding the second, its that when the code is run there is no ".group.detailed" so the second mousedown event is never attached to any elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take your two jQuery selections and merge them into one, use an `if()` to check if it's `.detailed` or not. you should also move those extra functions outside so that they're only defined once each.

i have rearranged the logic for you, now you need to fine tune the animation sequence: http://jsfiddle.net/V93dq/2/

Comment: Thanks vahapwns, I merged them into one and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

@vahanpwns is correct, try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/V93dq/1/

Basically you can use the hasClass jQuery method.

```
$('.group').mousedown(function(){
    var $self = $(this);

    if($self.hasClass("detailed")){

    }else{

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that's pretty similar to what I did after reading vahapwns answer.

Comment: This is exactly what OP needs, although I used `.is()` instead of `.hasClass()`, you got there before me :D

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here...
I used the condition hassClass... I think was better... And i prevent the link Default...

[Finddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48bsp/)

```
function readyAnimation (mySelf) {
    mySelf.css({display : 'block'});
    mySelf.css({'-webkit-box-sizing' : 'border-box', '-moz-box-sizing' : 'border-box', 'box-sizing' : 'border-box'});
    mySelf.css({margin : '0px'});
};

function resetAnimation (mySelf) {
    mySelf.css({display : ''}); 
    mySelf.css({'-webkit-box-sizing' : '', '-moz-box-sizing' : '', 'box-sizing' : ''});
    mySelf.css({margin : ''});
};

$('.group').mousedown(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("detailed")){
        var $self = $(this);
        var speed = 3250;
        var offset = {x : $self.offset().left, y : $self.offset().top};
        readyAnimation($self);
        $('.group').not($self).addClass('hide');
        $self.animate({'width' : '100%', 'height' : '+=' + '300px'}, {left: 'offset.x' + 'px', top: 'offset.y' + 'px'}, speed);
        $self.addClass('detailed');
    }else{
        var $self = $(this);
        var size = '300px';
        var speed = 3250;
        resetAnimation($self);
        $self.animate({'width' : size, 'height' : size}, speed)
        $('.group').removeClass('hide');
        $self.removeClass('detailed');
    }

}).find('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});;
```